# Printing Character with char data type

Tags: c

I have been trying to print the actual size of character stack in the console but it does not allow me to print numbers of character as of data size. Can somebody help me get the idea? I have created nodes with push, pop and display function to display the result. Character size is defined by a user so that they can print any number of character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    char data;
    struct node* next;
};

void init(struct node* head){
    head=NULL;
}

//push an element into the stack

struct node* push(struct node* head, int data){
    struct node* temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if(temp==NULL){
        exit(0);
    }
    temp->data=data;
    temp->next=head;
    head=temp;

    return head;
}

//to pop an element from the stack
struct node* pop(struct node *head, int *element){
    struct node* temp=head;
    *element=head->data;
    head=head->next;
    free(temp);
    return head;
}

//to display the element from the stack we transverse the stack element from the first element to NULL

void display(struct node* head){
    struct node* current;
    current=head;
    if(current!=NULL){
        printf("Stack: ");
            do{
                printf("%c", current->data);
                current=current->next;
            }
            while(current!=NULL);
            printf("\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("the stack is empty\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    struct node* head=NULL;
    char letter;
    int size;
    int counter=0;

    printf("Enter the number of stack elements");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    printf("---Push elements into the linked Stack---\n");

    init(head);

    while(counter<size){
        printf ("Enter a number to push into the stack:");
        scanf("%c",&letter);
        head = push(head,letter);
        display(head);
        counter++;
    }enter code here


    printf("--- Pop elements from the linked stack --- \n");
    while(empty(head) == 0)
    {
        head = pop(head,&letter);
        printf("Pop %c from stack\n",letter);
        display(head);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I think that I don't understand you well. Do you want to print a character as a number, like convert the character `'5'` in the integer `5`?

Comment: FYI, your parameters are `int` but you're passing `char`s.

Comment: Tip: Should you experience unexpected results, also print the `data` with sentinels and as a number for greater insight.  `printf("%c", current->data);` --> `printf("%d, <%c>", current->data, current->data);`

Answer (score 0):

You have probably been bitten by the input `%c` specifier. It gladly returns any character from the input stream, including spaces or newlines while all other specifiers skip over non printing characters. That means that for example you could have the following behaviour:

- enter 8 as the stack size
- answer <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

and... your stack is filled with the 8 characters: `'1'`, `'\n'`, `'2'`, `'\n'`, `'3'`, `'\n'`, `'4'`, `'\n'`!

Workaround: just answer the eight characters on one single line: 12345678<kbd>Enter</kbd>, the prompts will be displayed after the input, but at least you can fill your stack with what you want.

Solution: change your code to filter out new line character. You could also consider to replace `scanf("%c", &letter);` with a `%1s` specifier:

```
char dummy[2];           /* provide a place for the null */
...
scanf("%1s", dummy);     /* will skip over blanks and new lines */
letter = dummy[0];
```

And you should test the return value of input functions (`scanf`) to make sure that no IO problems occured...